# JavaScript If/Else Statements

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry for being slightly newbish, but I have a question. I generally try to learn through looking at examples and this one part of Javascript is giving me real trouble.

```
            if (lvl == "level0" || lvl == "level2" || lvl == "level3") {
                arr = window[lvl];
            } else {
                arr = window[lvl];
                arr = arr[dta];
            }
            var len = arr.length;

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                reslt = arr[i];
                reslt1 = reslt;

                document.getElementById(lvl).options[i + 1] = new Option(reslt1, reslt);
                document.getElementById(lvl).disabled = 0;
            }

        } // opened somewhere else
    } // opened somewhere else
```

I understand it to be a if/else statment with a for loop in the middle, but I can't not find arr, window or dta. I'm not sure if they are javascript specific and/or if I am just stupid. Thanks you for helpping.

Also if you have any good recommendation on any book or tutorials, I would appreciate it.

Comment: `window` the global object provided by the browser. The other two are coming from somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: Looking at your code example, there are 2 `}` left over at the bottom. This means you are missing code above this. That will be where those variables are set.

Comment: Also, you don't have "a if/else statment with a for loop in the middle", you have an if/else statement with a for loop after.

Comment: I've edited your question and added comments on the extra braces, so you can figure out things in a better way.

Comment: `lvl` and `dta` should be plain arrays, they might be defined in some external script file. Look for `<script src="[url here]"></script>` in the HTML and you should find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the number of braces, you'll see that the "if/else" part is all done and over with right before the `len = arr.length` statement.

You then have a `for` loop, with its own block of code.

After this, you have two closing braces. This tells us in no uncertain terms that there is code somewhere above that means that the piece you have given us is at least two levels deep.

As such, your question is unanswerable.

However, I can tell you that `window` is just the global object. It's where variables get shoved when you fail to use `var` on them.

`arr` is being defined in this very code, nothing special there.

`lvl` and `dta` is almost certainly defined elsewhere in your code, somewhere before this `if/else` block is run.